# How can I count entries in mySQL database faster?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, database-performance, rowcount

I am counting the entries in my SQL database:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM files WHERE id = ?";
$q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$q->execute([$id]);
$rowCount =$q->rowCount();
```

The result of `$rowCount` is 500000.
But to output this single number takes 5 seconds! Is it possible to get this result faster?

Comment: @PraveenKumar Thank you. What does "indexing" mean?

Comment: I won't be able to answer it effectively. Have a look at some random stuff: https://stackoverflow.com/q/13051246

Comment: @PraveenKumar Wouldn't `SELECT COUNT(id) FROM....` be quicker

Comment: @RiggsFolly _`*facepalm*`_ That's right.

Comment: @PraveenKumar :) :) :) :)

Comment: @BinarWeb You mean indexing?

Comment: Although half a million row with the same `id` value makes me think that `id` should have a better more informative name :)

Comment: @ThomasG Oh now I understand.

Comment: Sorry @BinarWeb I understood now.

Comment: It is true `COUNT(*)` is really fast!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the COUNT() function https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/counting-rows.html:

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM files WHERE id = ?";
```

Also ensure that 'id' is an indexed column:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-indexes.html

Answer (score 0):

1. Replace * with a field(use auto-increment id) - This will reduce the time a bit.
2. Index that field. - If you use indexed field the query performance will increase.

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT * ...`, then counting in PHP, requires shoveling all columns of all rows back to PHP.  That's a lot of effort for very little gain.

`SELECT COUNT(col) ...` does the counting in by MySQL, but it must check for whether `col` is `NULL`.  And it needs to get at the value of `col` for every row.

`SELECT COUNT(*) ...` counts the rows by whatever way is most efficient.  This involves looking for the 'smallest' index (or the whole table, if no secondary indexes), and counting through it.

You *must* learn about `INDEXes` to get anywhere in databases!  This is only one *minor* use for them.